# Using the word "out" after the word "thaw"

Tags: phrasal-verbs, etymology

What is the etymology of using the word "out" after "thaw"? For instance, "I put the food on the counter to thaw *out*." Are there any other such words that are customarily followed by "out" where "out" could be omitted and not change the meaning?

Comment: Out  is used used to make the meaning of a word stronger: like 
*We walked all day and were tired out (= very tired) by the time we got home.
It's up to you to sort this out (= deal with it completely).* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/out

Comment: Thawing is something that can be done partially, since it takes time and heat energy, and those are variable, so _thaw_ doesn't necessarily mean 'become completely unfrozen'. So something that does is useful, and that's what phrasal verbs are good for. As a particle on phrasal verbs, _out_ generally adds a completive sense. A fire _burns out_ or _goes out_ when there is no more fire; a frozen article _thaws out_ when there is no more frozen part.

Comment: @JohnLawler Could this be made an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thawing is something that can be done partially, since it takes time and heat energy, and those are continuously variable, so *thaw* doesn't necessarily mean 'become completely unfrozen'. Therefore, a verb that **does** mean that is useful, and that's what phrasal verbs are good for.

As a particle on phrasal verbs, *out* generally adds a completive sense to whatever the verb is. A fire *burns out* or *goes out* when there is no more fire; a frozen article *thaws out* when there is no more frozen part.